# Friendly URLs htaccess Rewrite Rule Regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am trying to figure out why my Rewrite Rule in my htaccess file is not changing the URL to a more "SEO Friendly URL".

Here´s an example of what I mean:

I want to go from this:

```
www.mydomain.com/Folder/post.php?url="how-to-make-me-a-happy-camper"
```

To this:

```
www.mydomain.com/Folder/how-to-make-me-a-happy-camper
```

or this:

```
www.mydomain.com/Folder/post/how-to-make-me-a-happy-camper
```

Here's the htacess code I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /post.php?url=$1
```

or without the post/

I seem to have trouble making the regex work, because when I follow a link it takes me to
`www.mydomain.com/Folder/post.php?url=how-to-make-me-a-happy-camper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question is confusing (The description says the opposite of what the rewrite rule indicates) and doesn't have all the required information, you may try this in one .htaccess file in root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !post\.php             [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Folder               [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*/([^/]+)/? /Folder/post.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://www.mydomain.com/Folder/post/anything` or

`http://www.mydomain.com/Folder/anything`

To

`http://www.mydomain.com/Folder/post.php?url=anything`

Strings `post` and `anything` are assumed to be variable while `Folder` and the script name (post.php) are assumed to be fixed.

For permanent and visible redirection, replace [L] with [R=301,L]

Comment: it works great except that all the css is messed up. Any idea to what might have caused this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: That's because the paths are different. You should use absolute paths or include the URI base in the header of your pages: `<base href="/whatever">` in between the <head> </head> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use RewriteBase option in your htaccess file.

```
 RewriteBase / #( or if your document root in a subfolder named Folder: /Folder/ )
```

And you should add two RewriteCondition, so your .htaccess file (it is not connect to your topic but recomend if you use apache rewrite_mod) should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /Folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # the requested uri does not points to a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # the requested uri does not points to a directory
RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ post.php?url=$1
```

And of corse the .htacces file should be where your post.php file is. (in this case in directory named Folder)